# Random Number Gen to give out a word with a button click

Tags: string, random, generator

I have been working on some code so, once a button is clicked then a random word from a string will be shown in the place of a textView. BUT I have forgotten how to do it! This is what I have so far.

```
                Button genBnt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.genBnt);
    genBnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

    String wordList[] = new String[30];

    wordList[0] = "Word One";
    wordList[1] = "Word Two";
    wordList[2] = "Word Three";

    int text = randomGenerator.nextInt(30);
    String wordToDisplay = excues[randomInt];       
        }
    });
}
```

}

So I have got the string done, but I have forgotten where to go from there, I have gotten some of this code from online.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I have forgotten"?

Comment: Verb
1.Fail to remember.
2.Inadvertently neglect to attend to, do, or mention something: "she forgot to lock her door"; "I'm sorry, I just forgot".

Comment: I meant, "forgotten" implies some previous knowledge that might be useful in understanding what you are actually asking. Please try to provide as much detail as possible. You should provide the whole class, you should add what you tried, where it failed and what you thought was working but then slipped out of your mind. Please don't expect people here to "autocomplete" you code, also because with the information you provided up to now, it's impossible (e.g. what `Button` are you referring to? AWT?)